# How to pass value to a field which is not added to page layout using URL hack

Tags: apex

I want to pass some value to a field that is not added to standard page layout using URL

As of now if that field is added to page layout then only I'm able to pass it else I'm not.

Comment: if a field is not added to page layout it means that field doesn't require any user input it means that field can be filled behind the scene using any other process. i.e. trigger, lightning process etc. can you describe your requirement in details so that we can have a context to tell you any alternative approach

Comment: need more info!

Comment: if  you want to fill fields value dynamic or from parent record then try with trigger or workflow to update those fields.

Comment: Not sure if Salesforce validates them, but you can play with retURL and saveURL which will point to your custom page which will update records accordingly. But as @Ratan mentioned, better option is trigger/workflow/process builder.

Comment: I just want to pass one field value and that field is not added in page layout.

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper why not try with workflow or trigger?

Answer (score 1):

The way URL hacks work is that when a page is loaded, any query string parameters that were passed into the page that have the same name as one of the form field ids will have the value populated in that form field. This means that a field must be in the form in order to be populated.

Your options are:

1. Create the form with Visualforce and either handle the query string parameters to populate the field in the controller. Advantage: you can populate the field in a supported way. Disadvantage: having to rewrite a whole page in Visualforce, and then figure out what to do later in Lightning Experience.
2. Use a quick action instead of the standard new/edit action, so that you can pass in the value you don't want on the form as a predefined value. Advantage: works in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1. Disadvantage: only supported in the Chatter Publisher in the classic desktop experience.
3. Use a workflow rule or process to populate the value when the record is saved. Advantage: will work in both classic desktop and Lightning Experience. Disadvantage: a little harder to maintain over time when you have fields getting populated from multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a workflow rule that will populate that field(s) when the object is saved. That way you don't have to URL-hack anything (and URL hacking is going away with the lightning experience) and you still get the record with the desired value.